# Hijack user input in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, input, xinput

For a program I am making, I want to grab every input (including mouse movements) of the user with my program and convert it into a fake xbox 360/One joystick. This is needed for a game I wanna play where a mouse and keyboard are way more convenient but not possible.

The idea is; you press a key (like Scroll Lock for instance) and the tool says; hey, I'm a joystick. When you press scroll lock again, everything is back to normal.

The catch is that the program I'm making, can't be the focussed window. How can one Hijack mouse/keyboard input? Converting it to xinput is another issue..

Comment: I think you should inquire about keylogers.

Comment: Good one! How didn't I think of that >.< Now the only thing I need is a way to prevent those keys to hit other Windows/screens